# Deep sleep for a specific time

Tags: toit

I need to activate a peripheral for a specific time, then sleep for some time, and then deactivate the peripheral again.

I could do this with a simple `sleep` but that would keep my ESP32 awake and burn battery. Is there a way to go into deep sleep for the required time and then wake up again?

Ideally I would simple schedule to run a deactivate program after a certain duration.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toit has the [following example](https://github.com/toitlang/toit/blob/master/examples/deep_sleep.toit) for putting an ESP32 into a deep sleep for 10 seconds.

```
// Copyright (C) 2021 Toitware ApS.
// Use of this source code is governed by a Zero-Clause BSD license that can
// be found in the examples/LICENSE file.

import esp32

main:
  run_time ::= Duration --us=esp32.total_run_time
  sleep_time ::= Duration --us=esp32.total_deep_sleep_time
  print "Awake for $(run_time - sleep_time) so far"
  print "Slept for $sleep_time so far"
  esp32.deep_sleep (Duration --s=10)
```